# Integer expression expected bash 2

Tags: shell-script

I'm just learning bash scripting. Tried to sort the array, it says "integer expression expected for lines 10 and 15. What am I doing wrong? Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=('5' '9' '0' '20' '2' '15' '6' '25' '1')
b=0
n=${#array[@]}
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "$n" ]
do
    c=${array[$i]}
    d=${array[$i+1]}
    if [ "$c" -lt "$d" ]; then
        j=0
        while [ "$j" -le "$i" ]
        do
            f=${b[$j]}
                if [ "$f" -gt "$c" ];
                    then b[$j]=$c
                    echo "${b[$j]}"
                fi
            j=$(( j+1 ))
        done
    fi
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

Comment: You seem to be using `$b` first as a scalar (`b=0`) and then later as an array (`${b[$j]}`).

Comment: What is the significance of the "2" in the title of this question?

Comment: thank you Stephane , how can I declare the array currectly ?

Comment: Running your script with `bash -x ./the-script` should make it apparent what the problem is. Again, look at your usage the `$b` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `[` command with the `-lt`/`-gt` decimal integer comparison operators on operands that are not always decimal integers.

You can see what happens if you run the script with `bash -x`. You'll see things like:

```
+ f=
+ '[' '' -gt 0 ']'
./myscript: line 15: [: : integer expression expected
```

With:

```
while [ "$i" -lt "$n" ]
do
[...]
   d=${array[$i+1]}
```

On the last pass in that loop, you'll try to access beyond the last element of the array, so `$d` will be empty.

You're also initialising `$b` as a 0 string, and later on accessing it as an array. See also how `f=${b[$j]}` will get you an empty `$f` except for when `$j` is 0.

I don't know what you're trying to do with that code, but it seems like you need to go back to the drawing board.